# Drupal 6 CCK node form redirect issue

Tags: drupal, forms, redirect, submit, cck

I am having trouble with a multi-step node form for a CCK content type. I set $form_state['redirect'] to a thank you page path, but it does not get redirected upon successful submission. Here is the code following documentation on the Drupal 5.x to 6.x form API at http://drupal.org/node/144132

function rnf_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 // ...
 $form['#submit'][] = 'rnf_regret_form_submit';
}

function rnf_regret_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
 $form_state['redirect'] = 'content/forget-thank-you';
}

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Figured it out, thanks to someone who had posted the same problem and its answer. In my code above, for node forms, the line 
$form['#submit'][] = 'rnf_regret_form_submit'
should read
$form['buttons']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'rnf_regret_form_submit'

Answer (score 1):

Ny guess is that you forget to clear $form_state['storage']. It needs to be empty before redirecting will work.

Comment: Actually I cleared it in the validate function:
function rnf_regret_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
 // ... if last page of form ... then clear
 unset($form_state['storage']);
}

Comment: ... and I am redirected to the node view page after the node is created.

Comment: ... but I want to be redirected to 'content/forget-thank-you' instead.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a multistep node form in Drupal 6 is a world of pain. You are a lot better off creating your own form and node_submit/node_save at the end. Roping in CCK widgets into this is a bit of a challenge but not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, thanks to someone who had posted the same problem and its answer. In my code above, for node forms, the line

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'rnf_regret_form_submit';
```

should read

```
$form['buttons']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'rnf_regret_form_submit';
```